# What Does Putting Two Constant Signs On A Function Parameter Do?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what two constant signs on a function parameter does in this case?

```
void virtual_via_pointer( const Employee * const );
```

Comment: The pointer and the pointee are both const.

Comment: @ShanePowell, It definitely is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to function parameters.

```
const Employee*
```

Means a "mutable pointer to a constant instance of `Employee`".

```
Employee* const
```

Means a "constant pointer to a mutable instance of `Employee`".

```
const Employee* const
```

Means a "constant pointer to a constant instance of `Employee`".

See also the [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: That is a pretty cool way of thinking of it. Thank you, that helps alot

Answer (score 0):

The pointer and the pointee are both constant.